# Cannot log in to mariadb from node.js app

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb-10.4

I can log in with the same credentials from Windows Command Line and from MariaDB admin.
But trying to log in from node.js app fails...

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: 'localhost', 
     user:'nikol', 
     password: 'nbuser',
     database: 'nodedb'
});
```

I get that error:

SqlError: Error during pool initialization: (conn=197, no: 1045, SQLState: 28000) Access denied for user 'nikol'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I can also log in as root user from command line, but not from node js app.
Any suggestions?

Comment: try with mysql client locally: ```mysql -u nikol -pbnuser -h localhost nodedb```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. When installing MariaDB, I changed port number from 3306 to 3300 and that caused the problem. Now I have reinstalled MariaDB and everything works ok.